# Paste the current clipboard content via code

Tags: android, copy

I searched for this but haven't found any viable answer.

My current Android app copies a content into the clipboard, is there any way for the app to force pasting it (via the Android copy and paste) after a certain type?

Thank you!

Comment: If you have the clipboard data you can just use it, don't need to paste the content

Answer (score 1):

How are you copying it to the Clipboard?

You can paste it by using the ClipboardManager (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ClipData.html)

```
ClipboardManager mClipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
ClipData clipData = mClipboard.getPrimaryClip();
ClipData.Item item = clipData.getItemAt(0); //first item from your clipboard.
```

Comment: My problem is that I copy to the Clipboard and open up a Facebook dialog, this Facebook dialog should get text that was collected before, I can not simply post it there!

Comment: Should add that info to your question.
I don't believe that  what you are trying to do with the facebook dialog is possible. You could do something if it were your own webview where you wanted to paste your data but i don't think you have access to the Facebook Webview Login dialog.